# Determine the solution set of $1=1-\sqrt{2}\cos(2x-\frac{\pi}{4})$ in the range $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I tried:

$$1 = 1-\sqrt{2}\cos(2x-\frac{\pi}{4})\Leftrightarrow \\
0 = -\sqrt{2}\cos(2x-\frac{\pi}{4}) \Leftrightarrow \\
0 = \cos(2x-\frac{\pi}{4})\Leftrightarrow \\
2x-\frac{\pi}{4} = \arccos(0)+2k\pi \lor 2x-\frac{\pi}{4} = -\arccos(0)+2k\pi \Leftrightarrow \\
2x-\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \lor 2x-\frac{\pi}{4} = -\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \Leftrightarrow \\
2x = \frac{3\pi}{4}+2k\pi \lor 2x = -\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi \Leftrightarrow \\
x = \frac{3\pi}{8}+k\pi \lor x = -\frac{\pi}{8}+k\pi$$

Then I tried several values for $k$ and the values of $x$ within the given interval are as follows:

$$\frac{3\pi}{8}+0\pi = \frac{3\pi}{8}$$
$$\frac{3\pi}{8}+\pi = \frac{11\pi}{8}$$
$$-\frac{\pi}{8} +0\pi= -\frac{\pi}{8}$$
$$-\frac{\pi}{8} + \pi = \frac{7\pi}{8}$$

And so the solution I get is $$\{-\frac{\pi}{8}, \frac{3\pi}{8},\frac{7\pi}{8}, \frac{11\pi}{8}\}$$

But my book says the solution is 
$$\{-\frac{3\pi}{8},\frac{3\pi}{8},\frac{7\pi}{8}, \frac{11\pi}{8}\}$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe a typo in the book, since $$\cos\left[2\left( -\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)-\frac{\pi}4\right]=\cos\left(-\pi\right)=-1\neq 0$$

Comment: Agreed. $x= -3\pi/8$ is not a solution to that equation.